Cobb-Douglas Utility function. Kindly help me derive it for a continuum of goods

The Cobb-Douglas utility function for a continuum of goods is used in the Dornbusch Fisher Samuelson Model (1977) model (DFS Model (1977)).

DFS model extends the 2-country, 2-good Ricardian Model to a continuum of goods.

Cobb-Douglas utility function for a continuum of goods:
(a) There is a continuum of goods indexed by z in [0, 1].
(b) 

The Cobb-Douglas function for a continuum of goods is probably derived as the limit of a Riemann sum for n finite goods:
(a) Start with the standard Cobb-Douglas function for a discrete number
of goods.
(b) Progressively divide the goods into smaller and smaller "bins" while
adjusting the weight of each bin.
(c) Take the limit as the number of bins approaches infinity.


This process effectively transforms the summation into a definite
integral, representing the utility derived from the continuum of goods.
(https://tomgschmitz.wordpress.com/wpcontent/uploads/2020/09/all_notes2021.pdf)
(https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+derive+cobb+douglas+utility+function+for+a+continuum+of+goods+as+a+limit+of+a+riemann+sum+for+n+finite+goods&oq=how+to+derive+cobb+douglas+utility+function+for+a+continuum+of+goods+as+a+limit+of+a+riemann+sum++for+n+finite+goods&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCjM5NzkxajBqMTWoAgiwAgE&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Utility functions for a continuum of goods come under "General Equilibrium in Infinite Product Spaces". Economists use advanced tools like optimal control, functional analysis, measure theory, fixed point theorems etc. to analyse such systems.

Few Examples:
(a) Equilibrium Theory in Infinite Dimensional Spaces:
Khan and Yannelis (1991)
(https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-07071-0#:~:text=Apart%20from%20the%20underlying%20theme%20that%20all,dimensional%20space%2C%20they%20differ%20on%20many%20counts)
(b) Chapter 34 Equilibrium theory in Infinite Dimensional Spaces:
Mas-Collel and Zame (1991)
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1573438205800098)
(c) An Economy with Infinite Dimensional Commodity Space and Empty Core:
Aliprantis etal (1987)
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0165176587901911)

Kindly provide a beginner-intermediate level reference for studying "General Equilibrium in Infinite Commodity/Product Spaces"


What is a Cobb-Douglas utility function for a continuum of goods?
